# How to prove that partial order is isomorphic a linear order

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to solve a question in discrete mathematics, but I do not understand how to solve it...

The question: Is a partial order (set with four elements) isomorphic a linear order with three elements? With four elements?

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: An isomorphism between partial orders is a bijection, and every linear order is a partial order, so a partial order with four elements cannot be isomorphic to a linear order with three elements. A partial order with four elements *can* be a linear order, in which case it is trivially isomorphic to a linear order with four elements, but it need not be one: for example, the partial order $\langle\wp(\{0,1\}),\subseteq\rangle$ has four elements and is not a linear order (because $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are not comparable), so it is not isomorphic to any linear order.

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what your question is, so feel free to elaborate, but here is some information that may help.

A *partial order* on a set $X$ is a relationship $\preceq$ between members of the set which is reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive. For example, the usual numerical order  $\leq$ on natural numbers is a partial order, and so is the "__ is an ancestor of __" relation on people.

Some partial orders have elements that are not related to each other. For example, for the partial order "__ is an ancestor of ___", you can find people (such as cousins) where neither person is an ancestor of the other person. A *linear order* on a set $X$ is a special type of partial order where every element is related to every other element—which allows you to order them in a "line". The $\leq$ order on integers is a linear order. The ancestor relation on people is not a linear order.

If you have a function between two partially-ordered sets, you can ask whether the function is *order-preserving* or not. A function $f$ which sends points in $X$ to points in $Y$ is *order-preserving* if for any pair of points $a\preceq b$ in $X$, we have that $f(a) \sqsubseteq f(b)$ in $Y$.

For example, the following map is order-preserving: the map sending $\langle \mathbb{N}, \leq\rangle$ to $\langle \mathbb{N}, \leq\rangle$ by multiplying every number by two. Because, after all, if $a\leq b$, then $2a\leq 2b$. But the map which sends each number to its remainder modulo 3 is *not* order preserving, since many pairs of numbers are mapped in a way that doesn't respect the order. For example $5\leq 7$ is mapped to $2 \not\leq 1$.

Finally, two partially-ordered sets are *isomorphic*—meaning that they're both essentially the *same* set with the *same* order—if there is a function between $X$ and $Y$ which (1) is bijective (2) is order-preserving (3) has an inverse which is order-preserving.

---

Here are some facts you can prove that may help you:

- Every linearly-ordered set with $n$ elements is isomorphic to every other linearly-ordered set with $n$ elements.
- For each partially-ordered set with $n$ elements, you can find an order-preserving map into a linearly-ordered set with $n$ elements.